# NOT Working: Wordpress Contact Form 7 (CF7) plugin add is_page condition inside "wpcf7_before_send_mail"

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have wrote this code in Wordpress theme functions.php, but is_page() is not working. Every time it is going to else condition. I have the JS solution, but the requirement is PHP solution.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_do_something_else_with_the_data', 90, 1 );
 
function wpcf7_do_something_else_with_the_data( $WPCF7_ContactForm ){
 
    // Submission object, that generated when the user click the submit button.
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission :: get_instance();
 
    if ( $submission ){
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();      
        if ( empty( $posted_data ) ){ return; }
 
        // Got name data
        $name_data = $posted_data['your-name'];
 
        if( is_page( 41235 ) ) {
            // Do my code with this name
            $changed_name = 'something with is page condition';
        } else {
            // Do my code with this name
            $changed_name = 'something is in else condition';
        }
 
        // Got e-mail text
        $mail = $WPCF7_ContactForm->prop( 'mail' );
 
        // Replace "[your-name]" field inside e-mail text
        $new_mail = str_replace( '[your-name]', $changed_name, $mail );
 
        // Set
        $WPCF7_ContactForm->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $new_mail ) );
    }
 
    return $WPCF7_ContactForm;
}
```

all possible way tried, multiple functions, connected functions, global variable etc.
but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick solution:
add hidden field to get the page/post ID then do the rest :)
thanks

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_new_form_tag' );
function wpcf7_new_form_tag() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'post_id', function ( $tag ) {
        return '<input type="hidden" value="'.get_the_id().'" name="post-id">';
    } );
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_do_something_else_with_the_data', 90, 1 );
 
function wpcf7_do_something_else_with_the_data( $WPCF7_ContactForm ){
 
    // Submission object, that generated when the user click the submit button.
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission :: get_instance();
 
    if ( $submission ){
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();      
        if ( empty( $posted_data ) ){ return; }
 
        // Got name data
        $name_data = $posted_data['your-name'];
        $page_id = $posted_data['post-id'];
 
        if( $page_id == 41235 ) {
            // Do my code with this name
            $changed_name = 'something with is page condition';
        } else {
            // Do my code with this name
            $changed_name = 'something is in else condition';
        }
 
        // Got e-mail text
        $mail = $WPCF7_ContactForm->prop( 'mail' );
 
        // Replace "[your-name]" field inside e-mail text
        $new_mail = str_replace( '[your-name]', $changed_name, $mail );
 
        // Set
        $WPCF7_ContactForm->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $new_mail ) );
    }
 
    return $WPCF7_ContactForm;
}
```